# visual basic in visual studio 2017 intellisense if statement with parentheses broken

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Since updating to Visual Studio 2017 I have observed unwanted behavior when constructing if statements, in that intellisense doesn't recognize variable names when I attempt to surround the clause in parenthesis. Consider the following incomplete code:

```
class AnythingClass
    ....
end class

public Sub doSomething()
  Dim anythingInstance as new AnythingClass
  if anyt
```

When typing code in this manner, the instance "anythingInstance" will be suggested by autocomplete. However, if I open parentasis when starting the if clause as below

```
class AnythingClass
    ....
end class

public Sub doSomething()
  Dim anythingInstance as new AnythingClass
  if (anyt
```

then the declared variable will not show in the autocomplete suggestions. The class name AnythingClass will show up in the suggestions, but not the instance

### UPDATE

(edit) ***THIS ANALYSIS IS INCORRECT***, please see my answer for details as to why

I have tried creating a brand new project and get the expected behavior. So this only appears to happen in projects that have previously been upgraded from older versions of visual studio.

I have attached a couple of screenshots for the skeptics!

[image: Working without parenthesis]

[image: Broken with parenthesis]

Comment: Works just fine on my machine.  When you ask for help with VS2017 then it is very, very important to mention the VS version.  Visible in Help > About, mine is 15.9.3  Keeping it updated is also very important, early releases had lots of bugs.

Comment: this is happening for me when working with VB.NET using on Visual Studio v15.9.3, both when upgraded from older versions and as a fresh install on a clean system.

Comment: Hmm, I like my 15.9.3 version better than yours.  If you are convinced you are doing it right, in spite of the lack of any evidence, then use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce this either. Btw, Visual Studio 15.9.7 available now.

Comment: See update. This issue does not seem to affect brand new projects, only ones previously imported from an old version of Visual Studio. Still occurs on 15.9.7

Comment: There might be an issue with how Visual Studio brings forward its various auxiliary files, especially given that you don't see it with a new project.  I'd suggest deleting the .vs folder in the solution folder to force VS to regenerate the auxiliary files and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Craig thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that hasn't helped :(

Comment: Sorry, but i can't reproduce your issue. BTW: there's small difference between `If`'s with parenthesis or without parenthesis. See: [If operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) and [If statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Comment: I can confirm this glitch exists in VS 15.9.6 (VS 2017). I believe I noticed this VS2015, but can not reproduce it with Update 3 that I have installed.  It is very subtle in that it is dependent upon whether or not you type a space before the opening parenthesis.  Without the space the issue manifests itself.  This occurred on new projects.

Comment: Thanks @MaciejLos and TnTinMn - analyzing both your comments has helped me 'solve' the issue (see answer). I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended behavior though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from @Maciej Los and @TnTinMn, I have managed to piece together the issue.

If you write the code as:

```
IF (an...
```

with a whitespace between the IF and the arguments, Then autocomplete appears to treat it as an If *statement* and will display instance variables. However if you write the code as

```
IF(an...
```

with no whitespace, autocomplete appears to treat it as the If *operator* and not show declared instances. Quite why this is the case, I don't know. My original analysis of there being a difference between new projects and previously imported ones was incorrect.